# Add values from a txt to a csv new column

Tags: python, csv

I want the data in test.txt to add under the "Results" columns in result.csv.
How can I accomplish the task? I tried many ways but I am not able to finish.

BTW, it will be great if the two "Running Image" can be in the one cell. The row should be "version".

test.txt

```
Running Image: SMM_2x10G 
Running Image: SMM_2x10G
C100G
SystemUptime:1d,19h,40m,30s
CPU utilization is normal with 96.1 idle
Memory is with good with 50.00%
```

result.csv

```
Content                 Results
Version 
Product
System Uptime   
CPU status  
MemFree/MemTotal
```

The final result should be like this:

```
Content            Results
Version "          Running Image: SMM_2x10G 
                   Running Image: SMM_2x10G"
Product            C100G
System Uptime      SystemUptime:1d,19h,40m,30s
CPU status         CPU utilization is normal with 96.1 idle
MemFree/MemTotal   Memory is with good with 50.00%
```

Thank you in advance!

I think I found a way to do that :
The code will be like:

```
import pandas,sys
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.read_csv('result.csv')
df2=pd.read_csv('test.csv')
df3=pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)
print(df3)
with open('test-result.csv','w',encoding="utf-8") as f:
    df3.to_csv(f,index=False)
```

Then I reviewed my previous code and encountered a problem. Actually the test.csv is extracted from a log file with a lot of data. I use the "for...if.." 
get the data want. If the data cannot be found in the log, I want it finally print a blank row in the "test.csv", but with the "for ...if...else", I have many blank rows......

```
for line in fp:
      if "Unknown(255) Unknown" in line:
            Unknown = line_stream
            print("The module is in unknown status %s:" % line_stream, file=fp1)
      else:
            print("\n",file=fp1)
```

Knew how to solve by google....Thx.

Comment: Update your question with what you tried that didn't work.

Comment: Can you post an example fo what result.csv should look like? It looks to me like the schema you give has two columns and several rows, not vice versa.

Comment: I don't know how to paste the csv in the comment.. The data in the text.txt should all be under the Result columns in the result.csv. I am fresh for the csv. I know how to add data in column with a new csv but don't know how to add in the existing csv...Are you able to help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: to add to an existing csv file, open the csv file in the "append" mode: `with open("filename.csv", "a") as f:`

Comment: How can I add the data under the "Results" Column?  Thank you.

Comment: Don't try to add code or the CSV as a comment. Instead use the [edit] button to add more information to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way:

```
import pandas,sys
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.read_csv('result.csv')
df2=pd.read_csv('test.csv')
df3=pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)
print(df3)
with open('test-result.csv','w',encoding="utf-8") as f:
    df3.to_csv(f,index=False)
```